# Why does tar -c command remove leading `/' from member names

Tags: linux, bash, tar

Looking to find the practical reasons the command `tar -c /filea > /fileb` gives the following output: `tar:Removing_leading /` from member names.

I have researched it quite a bit but only come across very vague reasons such as protects against some sort of attack etc. The majority just give explanations on a workaround should you want it.

I do not want a workaround. I am simply curious as to the actual practical reasons for it happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's so that you don't unintentionally overwrite files in system directories.

Comment: SO is for programming questions. Questions about the design of Unix utilities are more appropriate for unix.SE.

Comment: Imagine someone sending you a tar file that contains `/etc/passwd`. If you extract it as root, and `tar` doesn't remove leading `/`, it will overwrite that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helps avoid mistakes which could cause important files to be overwritten. Files are normally extracted relative to the current working directory of the tar command.

Just Example:

If you archive /etc/httpd this directory it removes leading /. Because. If it exists after extract current /etc/httpd will overwrite  with archive /etc/httpd.

After removing the leading '/' it extract on your working directory. If you extract on /var/tmp directory it will kept as /var/tmp/etc/httpd